# Capistrano Deploy is throwing a missing gem error for a gem I have

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, rubygems, capistrano

I recently attempted a Capistrano deployment for my Rails app after adding the Thinking Sphinx and Whenever gems and the deployment is breaking. The message I'm seeing is quite strange. There's an error coming from CarrierWave, which is a gem I had previously installed and deployed several weeks ago with no problem.

`Could not find carrierwave-0.5.8 in any of the sources`

`Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.`

But when I ssh into my server and run `bundle install` I get this:

`Using carrierwave (0.5.8)`

`Your bundle is complete!`

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: It could be the context in which you're running commands from your deploy task. The `cap shell` has helped me tremendously when debugging: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/9/21/introducing-the-capistrano-shell

Comment: That's a helpful tip, Damien, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a failed install of Thinking Sphinx that was somehow derailing the Cap deploy downstream. Poor error reporting! But I was able to get to the bottom of it that way.